# Replace Column if equal to a specific value

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I'm looking to replace the fourth column in a CSV if it equals `N/A`.  I'm trying to change it to `-1`.
  I can't seem to get this to work.

```
awk -F , '{ if($4 == "N/A") {$4 = -1} }' test.csv
```

Comment: It is fine, just that you have to print the result. Add `{print}` after the current `{ if }` block.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this will just print those lines that had `$4=="N/A"`, while I guess OP wants to have the full updated file as output.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the following `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{ $4 = ($4 == "N/A" ? -1 : $4) } 1' OFS=, test.csv
```

- We set the input and output field separators to `,` to preserve the delimiters in your csv file
- We check the forth field if it is equal to "N/A" then we assign it the value `-1` if not we retain the value as is.
- `1` at the end prints your line with or without modified 4th column depending if our test was successful or not.
- `($4=="N/A"?-1:$4)` is a ternary operator that checks if the condition `$4=="N/A"` is true or not. If true `?` then we assign `-1` and if false `:` we keep the field as is.

#### Test run on sample file:

```
$ cat file
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5,6
44,2,1,N/A,4,5
24,sdf,sdf,4,2,254,5
a,f,f,N/A,f,4
```

```
$ awk -F, '{ $4 = ($4 == "N/A" ? -1 : $4) } 1' OFS=, file
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5,6
44,2,1,-1,4,5
24,sdf,sdf,4,2,254,5
a,f,f,-1,f,4
```

Comment: +1 for the great explanation (though it's probably overkill to rebuild _every_ input line by always assigning to `$4`). Can I suggest putting a space before the final `1` to better indicate that it is a _separate_ command (pattern with implied action)?

Comment: I like the `else` possibility, +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is another `awk` (using example data from jaypal)

```
awk -F, '$4=="N/A" {$4=-1}1' OFS=, file
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5,6
44,2,1,-1,4,5
24,sdf,sdf,4,2,254,5
a,f,f,-1,f,4
```

Comment: `ofs` is a built in variable and the output field separator, see [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in `sed`,

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),N\/A,(.*)$/\1,\2,\3,-1,\4/g' file
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5,6
44,2,1,-1,4,5
24,sdf,sdf,4,2,254,5
a,f,f,-1,f,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative for awk, and a shorter regex for sed:
I used a regex containing the separator characters on both sides.

If your file is tab separated you can use `\t` instead of `,`.

```
sed 's/,N\/A,/,-1,/g' infile.csv >  outfile.csv
```

Replace on the same file, good for big files, test before using !!

```
sed -i 's/,N\/A,/,-1,/g' infile.csv
```